# How do you configure Commerce Authoring Service without SSL / TLS

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I try to setup Sitecore commerce 8.2.1 using the steps in the documentation by sitecore (http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DevOpsGuide/en-us/index.html).

If the Commerce Authoring Service, wants to connect to Sitecore, a connection is always set up via SSL.

#### Connection, observed with fiddler

[image: Connection, observed with fiddler]

#### The Connector use always SSL

The Connector (Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager) use static https.

```
public static HttpResponseMessage ProcessRequest(SitecoreConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, string action, string method, ItemModel itemModel)
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}", connectionPolicy.Host));
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient{BaseAddress = baseAddress})
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So, the Commerce Authoring Service, will only work, if Sitecore runs with SSL.

For **PROD** environments, this is this fine.
But, for **DEV** environment, we would like run Sitecore without SSL.

Is it possible to change this connector from **https** to **http**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to generate a [self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441155/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-a-domain-name-for-development) for DEV environment.

As you've mentioned in question description `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionManager` uses `https` in its source code. This class is widely used to access Sitecore items from Commerce Engine. `SitecoreConnectionManager` uses [Sitecore.Services.Client (SSC)](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/sitecoreservicesclient) to get information from Sitecore. 
To send API requests to SSC `SitecoreConnectionManager` first sends request for authentication to `sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login` endpoint that is available only over [https](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/sitecoreservicesclient_security):

> You must make requests to auth/login over HTTPS.

Note that Commerce Engine uses credentials from `SitecoreConnectionPolicy` to integrate with SSC. E.g.:

```
{
    "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management",
    "Host": "retail.dev.local",
    "SitecoreDatabase": "master",
    "UserName": "CommerceEngineUser",
    "Domain": "sitecore",
    "Password": "demopass",
    "PolicyId": "a12d609f37124c4fb9007519a8e18b69",
    "Models": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Model, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
        "$values": [

        ]
    }
}
```