# Issue with habitat.commerceengin.dev.local:5000/Api

Tags: habitat, sitecore-commerce

Hi I'm working on a POC using Sitecore Retail demo. Yesterday I imported all the images for every product, and now this error is showing on every page. Any idea?

```
4464 19:58:16 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Retail/Layouts/Retail.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Common/Sublayouts/Section.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Retail_Layouts_Retail_cshtml.Execute() in C:\websites\Habitat.dev.local\Website\Views\Retail\Layouts\Retail.cshtml:line 72
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Common/Sublayouts/ArticleAsideRight.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions.HtmlHelperExtensions.DynamicPlaceholder(SitecoreHelper helper, String placeholderName, Boolean useStaticPlaceholderNames) in C:\Projects\Habitat\src\foundation\SitecoreExtensions\code\Extensions\HTMLHelperExtensions.cs:line 60
   at ASP._Page_Views_Common_Sublayouts_Section_cshtml.Execute() in C:\websites\Habitat.dev.local\Website\Views\Common\Sublayouts\Section.cshtml:line 9
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions.HtmlHelperExtensions.DynamicPlaceholder(SitecoreHelper helper, String placeholderName, Boolean useStaticPlaceholderNames) in C:\Projects\Habitat\src\foundation\SitecoreExtensions\code\Extensions\HTMLHelperExtensions.cs:line 60
   at ASP._Page_Views_Common_Sublayouts_ArticleAsideRight_cshtml.Execute() in C:\websites\Habitat.dev.local\Website\Views\Common\Sublayouts\ArticleAsideRight.cshtml:line 9
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException
Message: An error occurred while processing this request.
Source: Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy
   at Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy.Proxy.GetValue[T](DataServiceQuerySingle`1 query)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.Pipelines.Prices.GetProductPrices.Process(ServicePipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Services.ServiceProvider.RunPipeline[TRequest,TResult](String pipelineName, TRequest request)
   at Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Managers.PricingManager.GetProductPrices(String catalogName, String productId, Boolean includeVariants, String userId, String[] priceTypeIds) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\code\Managers\PricingManager.cs:line 66
   at Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Managers.CatalogManager.GetProductPrice(ICatalogProduct productViewModel) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\code\Managers\CatalogManager.cs:line 169
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Catalog.Factories.ProductViewModelFactory.PopulatePriceInformation(ProductViewModel productViewModel) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Feature\Catalog\code\Factories\ProductViewModelFactory.cs:line 106
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Catalog.Factories.ProductViewModelFactory.Create(Item item) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Feature\Catalog\code\Factories\ProductViewModelFactory.cs:line 87
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Catalog.Models.CategoryViewModel..ctor(Item categoryItem, SearchResults products, IEnumerable`1 sortFields, SearchOptions searchOptions) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Feature\Catalog\code\Models\CategoryViewModel.cs:line 47
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Catalog.Factories.CategoryViewModelFactory.Create(Category category, SearchOptions productSearchOptions) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Feature\Catalog\code\Factories\CategoryViewModelFactory.cs:line 54
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Catalog.Controllers.CatalogController.GetCategoryViewModel(Category category, SearchOptions productSearchOptions) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Feature\Catalog\code\Controllers\CatalogController.cs:line 709
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Catalog.Controllers.CatalogController.ProductList(Nullable`1 pageNumber, String facetValues, String sortField, Nullable`1 pageSize, Nullable`1 sortDirection) in C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Feature\Catalog\code\Controllers\CatalogController.cs:line 207
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Nested Exception

Exception: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException
Message: {
  "@odata.context":"http://habitat.commerceengine.dev.local:5000/Api/$metadata#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.CommandMessage","MessageDate":"2017-09-13T19:58:14.1319894Z","Code":"Error","Text":"Management.block.getitembypath: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","CommerceTermKey":"Exception"
}
Source: Microsoft.OData.Client
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

After looking at the Commerce Server Catalog Manager, I realized the catalog was wiped, probably by one of the sync task I executed.

When restarting Sitecore, I now have a new log error. HTTPS is working properly.

```
2048 19:08:02 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'commercecacherefresh:remote' event.
Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source[1]: Sitecore.Kernel 
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.AddItemBasedTemplates(TemplateDictionary result)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.InternalGetTemplates()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.TemplateEngine.GetTemplate(ID templateId)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem.GetTemplate()
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Catalog.Pipelines.CatalogToSitecoreItemProcessor.Process(CatalogToSitecoreItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Catalog.CatalogProvider.GetItemFields(DataProvider dataProvider, ItemDefinition itemDefinition, VersionUri versionUri, CallContext context, ExternalIdInformation information)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Catalog.ReadOnlyCatalogDataProvider.GetItemFields(ItemDefinition itemDefinition, VersionUri versionUri, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetItemFields(ItemDefinition item, VersionUri version, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.LoadItemData(ItemDefinition itemDefinition, Language language, Version version)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemData(ID itemID, Language language, Version version)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.GetItem(ID , Language , Version , Database )
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.Execute(ID , Language , Version , Database )
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetItemUnderTestProcessor.Process(GetItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.CacheRefresh.RemoveItemFromSitecoreCaches(ID itemId, String databaseName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Caching.CacheRefresh.Refresh(String cacheEventName, ICommerceServerContextManager contextManager, String databaseName, ID itemId)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Events.CommerceCacheRefreshEventHandler.OnCacheRefresh(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) 


12048 19:08:02 ERROR Exception while handling event Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Events.CacheRefreshEvent
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'commercecacherefresh:remote' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.Subscription`1.Invoke(Object instance, EventContext context)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event, Type eventType, EventContext context)
```

### UPDATE

I used Fiddler to diagnose the calls, the http://habitat.commerceengine.dev.local:5000/api/$metadata call works correctly, but no surprise, I find the same error while trying to call http://retail.dev.local/shop/Televisions_televisions/.

So basically, all the calls done to commerceengine from retail demo are failing.

Answer (score 0):

`Management.block.getitembypath` goes to Sitecore through SSC. If it was working previously then try to check:

1. your Sitecore site can be still opened via https (required for SSC
   login call)
2. you didn't make critical security changes to your Sitecore item structure (note that credentials from
   `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.SitecoreConnectionPolicy` are
   used)
3. try checking your engine logs for `Management.GetItemByPath` lines. (e.g. `INFO Management.GetItemByPath.GetItem./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel` Check that items are presented in Sitecore

Comment: 1. HTTPS is not set on the website, and it didn't caused any problem before. 2. No security changes have been made and 3. there's folders in Commerce Control Panel such as Storefront settings.

Comment: 1. https is mandatory for your retail demo site. you may use it without https and it will work, but engine sends requests to https only. Check that https://retail.dev.local is working for you. Check [this answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/7430/139) for more details. 2. Ok 3. check logs for similar lines. You should have many lines starting with `INFO Management.GetItemByPath.GetItem.`

Comment: Retail.dev.local is working correctly. I got errors when I load a listing page, or a product page. When loading a product page, I got "The requested document was not found"

Answer (score 0):

I found out that CommerceEngineUser had been wiped. By adding it as an admin to Sitecore (with the password defined in line 215 in the Habitat.CommerceMinions-1.0.0.json), the communication is now resolved.

Make sure that this user is always in Sitecore.

Comment: Am closing this, as the error and ultimate cause of this problem adds very little value to the site. If you want to record a proper Q & A for this, open up a new question related to the service users and environment json files, and record your answer there.